# How to save raw html to sql with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working with [Ionize](http://ionizecms.com/) - i'm trying to save text with html tags to mysqli, but i keep getting the text like this :

```
   <p>&lt;div class="foo"&gt;foo&lt;/div&gt;</p>
```

while i want to get

```
    <div class="foo">foo</div>
```

I've tried to replace all the htmlspecialchars methods with html_entity_decode
but it didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to have it saved like that, you just have to apply htmlspecialchars_decode on your result before printing it.